# Collection view not reloading after retrieving data

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview, swift4.2

Situation: I'm pulling data from Firebase. After pulling the data, I want to update/reload my collectionView table.

Problem: collectionView doesn't update. Here are the codes with a bit of explanation.

```
var allProducts = [Product]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mostPopularCollectionView.dataSource = self
    mostPopularCollectionView.delegate = self

    getAllProducts { (returnedProductArray) in
        self.allProducts = returnedProductArray
        self.mostPopularCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

1. The function getAllProducts works fine. If I print allProducts.count within the closure, I get the right number(3).
2. If I print allProducts.count outside the closure, my count is zero.
3. I tried putting the getAllProducts function in viewWillAppear but it didn't solve the problem

   extension FeedTableViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate 
   {

   ```
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       return 3

   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mostPopularCell", for: indexPath) as? MostPopularCollectionViewCell else {return UICollectionViewCell()}


       if allProducts.count > 0 {
           let product : Product = allProducts[indexPath.row]
           if let productImageUrl = product.imageUrlArray.first {
               cell.upadateCellUI(forProductName: product.title, forProductImage: productImageUrl, forProductPrice: product.price)
           }
           return cell
       } else {
           return cell
       }

   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let productVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "productVC") as! ProductViewController
       productVC.product = allProducts[indexPath.row]
       present(productVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

   }

The good news is that when I click on any item, the right product is selected when the next viewController appears.

So the only issue is how do I get the collectionView to reload after data is retrieved  from Firebase? Any help is very much appreciated

This is the getAllProducts function used to retrieve all the data from Firebase.

```
//MARK:- Retrieve all products from Firebase
func getAllProducts (handler: @escaping (_ allProducts: [Product]) -> ()) {

    //TODO:- Create an empty array to store all product fetched from Firebase
    var productArray = [Product]()
    var imageUrlArray = [String]()

    //TODO:- Create reference to Firebase database
    let DB = Database.database().reference()

    //TODO:- Create reference to products
    let REF_PRODUCTS = DB.child("Product")

    //TODO:- Snapshot of all products in database
    REF_PRODUCTS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (allProductsSnapshot) in
        guard let allProductsSnapshot = allProductsSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

        for product in allProductsSnapshot {
            let title = product.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as! String
            let price = product.childSnapshot(forPath: "price").value as! String
            let id = product.childSnapshot(forPath: "id").value as! Int
            let viewCount = product.childSnapshot(forPath: "viewCount").value as! Int
            let description = product.childSnapshot(forPath: "description").value as! String

            let REF_IMAGEURL = REF_PRODUCTS.child(String(id)).child("image")

            REF_IMAGEURL.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (allImageUrlSnapshot) in
                guard let allImageUrlSnapshot = allImageUrlSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

                for imageUrl in allImageUrlSnapshot {
                    let imageUrl = imageUrl.value as! String
                    imageUrlArray.append(imageUrl)
                }
            })

            let product = Product(title: title, price: price, imageUrlArray: imageUrlArray, description: description, viewCount: viewCount, id: id)
            productArray.append(product)
        }
        handler(productArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show getAllProducts func also.

Comment: edited the initial post to include the getAllProduct function

Comment: If the collection view is not loading data then how do you select one of its items?

Comment: The collectionView reloads the data but doesn't update the UI. I guess that is a better way of putting it. Good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **always** update your UI elements on main thread. No exception here as well. Just execute the reload code on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
   self.mostPopularCollectionView.reloadData()
})
```

**For Swift 3:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
   self.mostPopularCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async { print("always a priceless tip!") }`

Answer (score 0):

your viewDidLoad is look like below:

```
    var allProducts = [Product]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    mostPopularCollectionView.dataSource = self
    mostPopularCollectionView.delegate = self

    getAllProducts { (returnedProductArray) in
        self.allProducts = returnedProductArray

     }
   self.mostPopularCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: you tried something wrong. In storyboard you set datasource and delegate of collectionview to your viewcontroller

Comment: I don't get what you mean. I've already set the delegate and datasource of the collectionView to the viewController. It will be easier for me if I could share my screen.

Comment: Reloading data before data is retrieved...

Answer (score 0):

This may be due the auto layout issue, I stuck in the same case and resolving the auto layout issue for the cell, enable debug log for view on the xcode. and see if there is any auto layout issue is there, remember the size of the content should be less than content of collection view